# Git- updating remote branch from another remote branch

Tags: git

In my project I have two branches Goa1 and Goa2 on the server and are accessible to all developers.

Goa1 is updated by multiple teams and Goa2 is for my team which should always be updated with changes from Goa1.

On my local machine I have these two local branches and I keep on getting changes from Goa1. At the moment there is no active development on Goa2, however, I wish to keep it updated for future. So to do this what I did is as follows

```
$git checkout Goa1

$git pull origin Goa1
```

Goa1 is updated with latest change from server

```
$git checkout Goa2

$git pull origin Goa1
```

local branch Goa2 is updated with all checkins from Goa1

Now I am trying to push the updated commits from local Goa2 to remote Goa2 by following command which fails.

```
$git push origin Goa2:refs/for/Goa2

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To https://blahblah.com/greatProject
 ! [remote rejected] Goa2 -> refs/for/Goa2 (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://blahblah.com/greatProject'
```

Is there anything that I am missing? I am under impression that since my HEAD in local Goa2 is updated to something new, above command should push the changes to the branch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What evidence do you have that your pulls added new commits?

Comment: I could see Goa2 branch's HEAD pointing to the latest commit of Goa1.

Comment: It would be that way if it was that way before and nothing got added, too.

Comment: well, No, I am sure that the HEAD was pointing to something else earlier. And after pulling the log showed me lots of changes pulled from Goa1 on command line.

Comment: So show the evidence you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's go through what you tried to do here:

Your first step "$git checkout Goa1" simply ensures that you are on the Goa1 branch
Your second step "$git pull origin Goa1" pulls ONLY Goa1 updates (you might want to pull all updates)
Your third step "$git checkout Goa2" now makes you change branch to Goa2
Your fourth step "$git pull origin Goa1" now pulls in code from Goa1, BUT it does *not* add anything to that actual branch.  So when you try and push those changes without using "git add" for those new changes, it simply states that no new changes are there.  You basically did this:

```
git checkout Goa1
//create some awesome code
//ooops forgot to say "git add ."
//ooops forgot to say "git commit -m 'blah blah some awesome code'"
git push origin Goa1
```

What you want to do is in the TL;DR section

TL;DR

```
git checkout Goa1
git pull origin
git checkout Goa2
git merge origin/Goa1
```

Comment: well I followed those steps.

git checkout Goa1
git pull origin
git checkout Goa2
git merge origin/Goa1

however, after this I wanted to push changed local Goa2 branch to remote. And this didnt work. the result is same 

$git push origin Goa2:refs/for/Goa2

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To https://blahblah.com/greatProject
 ! [remote rejected] Goa2 -> refs/for/Goa2 (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://blahblah.com/greatProject'